# How to run a script immediately after the start splash screen appears?

Tags: boot, init.d

I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I'd like to know where I can put the script of mine described below to run immediately after the splash screen of the initialization begins.

```
#!/bin/sh
contrast=`echo "scale=2;6/10.0" | bc`
brightness=`echo "scale=2;40/1.0" |bc`
xgamma -quiet -gamma $contrast
xbacklight -set $brightness
```

PS.: This script (for while) changes the brightness and the contrast of my screen. I would like to improve it to perform other things but first I need to know how can I solve the problem described above.

Comment: I don"t want to spoil your plan, but since X11 is only started after the splash screen disappears, your script will probably not work while the splash screen is still up. Anyhow, if you want to add scripts to system startup, read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto#Writing_Services

Comment: Hum, I will take a look. But If needed, I will do another script to start with my gui interface too.